# Indexing allowing for specific versions or a record

Tags: c#, database

I've recently acquired a database design from a previous employee of the company, an employee who was renowned for over engineering and reinventing the wheel.

We're working with MySql running on an embedded device programmed in C# .Net Version 4. The device we're working on is providing automated QC Testing for scientific instruments.

Since all results need to link back to the Method they used we need to track versions of the Methods within the Result structure.

Currently for each Method we use 4 fields to do this: ID, RootId, Version and Status. To make things easier, the last guy decided that Guids would be the easiest form of keys so each record now has two Guid and 2 Integers just to do the indexing.

My thinking is that there must be an easier way to do this? We're looking at replacing the Guids with Int but at the same time, I don't know if that's the real issue.

I'm curious as to how other people tackle a problem like this?

Comment: What's the actual problem, is querying the data slow? Why does each record have two ids, that's just wrong.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? You are having any issue with speed of record fetching? I think you should change ID field's data type to big int and keep RootId's data type to GUID.

Comment: We're still too early into the project at this point to tell if things are slow but at this stage we don't have any live systems so we're free to change for new ideas. I acquired this project from another guy and with my very small amount of database experience, I still feel there must be a better way, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: As you said yourself, "why reinvent the wheel" when the program is working as required. We can help you if you have a real issue. If you think database table structure can be improved, please add an image of the database model.